# What is the flaw in my thinking in this javascript boolean function?

Tags: javascript, logic

So I am suppose to create a function that reverses a values boolean parameter. [Here][1] is what I came up with:

[image]

I really just want to understand what is my flaw in thinking. How can I fix my approach?

Comment: input parameter x is never used in the function.

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look to your code:

```
function not(x) {
    if (1 == true) {
        return "true";
    } else if (0 == false) {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

1. Whats right:

   ```
   function not(x) {

   }
   ```
2. Whats goes wrong:

   ```
   if (1 == true) {
   //  ^ ^^ ^^^^
   //  | |  boolean
   //  | equal (not type safe)
   //  number
   ```

   You compare constant values. In this case a number `1` with a boolean `true`. The comparison operator is [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_()) `==` and this "*converts the operands if they are **not of the same type***". That means that one is equal true and the next part is evaluated and

   ```
   return "true";
   ```

   ever, because there are no variables involved. The rest of the else part is never reached, as well as the next comparison, which is never reached.

   As well as `'true'` is always returned, it is not the type you want, because you need a boolean and return a string.
3. What should change:

   ```
   if (x == true) {
   //  ^
   //  the parameter of the function

       return true;
       //     ^
       //     boolean

   } else {
   //     ^
   // no other if

       return false;
       //     ^
       //     boolean
   }
   ```

   or a short version of all with the [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)) operator `!`:

   ```
   function not(x) {
       return !x;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to write the function for learning purpose, because you do not need to write it in practice. Javascript already has ! (not) operator.
For your function and implementation would be:

```
function not(x) {
     if(x === true) return false;
     else return true;
}
```

But as I said you can just use ! operator.